# Android: How to add new code for already exisitng binary (apk) file

Tags: android

I have an applications binary (.apk) file, don't have source code of it and i want to add a  new code which will collect the device info and verifies it with a validation server and then starts the main activity.

How to add new code into the existing binary file. What are the limitations? What are different things we need to accomplish this task?

looking for Google Play licensing kind of approach for on-premise applications.

In other words, how to do the licensing for private apps whose binaries are available but not the source code.

Comment: Bear in mind that what you are describing may be a copyright violation in any nation subscribing to the Berne Convention, as you will be creating a derivative work without license to do so. Your first requirement, therefore, is to consult with qualified legal counsel to determine the legality of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you would need to rewrite the application. Even if you were able to decompile the application, add changes, and recompile it (which is sometimes possible), you would truly be a fool for taking that approach, considering you would not be able to effectively maintain the application.

Edit -- technically, you could even maintain it through that method, but many things are infinitely more possible than they are practical.